# How to reload the file type control with latest file content with out refresh and browse button

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

In my application I having file type control and button for upload.
In that screen I need to validate the excel sheet. At very first time I have uploaded with missing data, so validation matches and I need to show the validation message. After that I am filling all the required data in excel sheet
and click the upload button without refresh the page or without selecting the browse button. I didn't get the modified the content of the excel sheet.

code:

```
<input id="filebutton" name="filebutton" type="file"/>
<input type="button" value="Upload" id="btnupload"/>
```

Please provide the solution to get latest content from the upload file.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. It would be helpful to understand more of your code, what you have tried so far. Please edit your post or comment with the details of what you have tried so far.

Comment: Initially I have selected excel file to upload, then I am modified the file content of the excel file. with out refreshing the page and reselecting the file again. I want to get modified content(latest) from the path by clicking the button

Comment: This does not clarify the issue. What ate you using to modify the file?